# Searching // select * from database with 2 columnes laravel //

Tags: mysql, laravel

how to select * from database with 2 columnes

```
 $search = $request->get('search');
        $projects = new Project();
        $projects = $projects->where('description', 'like', '%' . $search .  '%')
        ->orderBy("id")
          ->paginate(10)
           ->withPath('?search=' . $search);
           return view('projects.index', compact('projects'));
```

Comment: It's not clear what are you asking. Please try to explain what exactly would you like to achieve.

Comment: i want to select description and created_at / 2 columns sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search by two these columns with:

```
->where('description', 'like', '%' . $search .  '%')
->orWhere('created_at', '<', now())
```

Comment: oops i mean search through those 2 columns

Comment: @М.Билгүүн do you want to search by these with using `AND` or `OR`?

Comment: 'OR' sir description or created_at

Comment: @М.Билгүүн the example will search by `description` and by `created_at` date using `OR`

Answer (score 0):

You can add this values to a data. After all just get data.

```
$search = $request->get('search');
        $projects = new Project();
        $projects = $projects->where('description', 'like', '%' . $search .  '%')
        ->orderBy("id")
          ->paginate(10)
           ->withPath('?search=' . $search);
             $data=array();
        foreach ($projects as $key) {
                $data[]=array('value'=>$key->description.' '.$key->created_at);
           return view('projects.index', compact('projects'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, write a beautiful and simple code:

```
$projects = Project::select(\DB::raw("CONCAT(description, ' ', created_at) as value"))
    ->where('description', 'like', '%' . $request->search . '%')
    ->orderBy("id")
    ->paginate(10)
    ->withPath('?search=' . $request->search)

return view('projects.index', compact('projects'));
```